# If I wrote some code in Android's runtime. What should I do if I want to call this code in the app?

Tags: android, java-native-interface

Because of my lack of Android development skills, I don't know how to fix or find relevant information. If I wrote some code in Android's run time. What should I do if I want to call this code in the app?

I've written some code in run time. And push compiled .so to the phone. I dump some logs. It looks like they running well. But now,I don't know how to call this code in the app.Should I write some `JNI` code in run time? If so, do I still need load lib in the app?

Comment: Your description is very vague. You wrote some code, presumably in C++, and it runs in system  context and does something on your device. So far so good. If you want this code to communicate with some other code, running as an app, you need some interprocess communication mechanism. The easiest of such IPC protocols is Unix sockets.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you have to play with `JNI`. `JNI` will serve as a bridge between your `Java` code and native code `C/C++`

I suggest to start with something simple (not necessarily inside Android). Just to get the feeling of what to expect, you can start with simple `'Hello World'`.

http://jnicookbook.owsiak.org/recipe-No-001/

Basically, what you need, is to have your native code accessible from your `Java` code via `JNI`.

There are two options:

- you can pack all the stuff (your code and JNI based code) inside one `.so`
- you can also create two libraries: one with your native code and other one with `JNI` code

[image]

http://jnicookbook.owsiak.org/recipe-No-023/